# How to replace characters from URL vb.net?

Tags: string, vb.net, url, replace

I am posting request where I use certain values from the previous response and for example in response I get the decimal value `62.234` then I want this value to be parsed in my request, but the request somehow changes the values and it become `62,234` with "`comma`" and not "`dot`".

I tried to replace back the `,` for `.` but the problem is that the full request URL contains also another parameters arguments `{arg1}&{arg2}` where I can not change the "`,`" comma for a "`.`" because it will replace also another comma values which I need it stays comma.

So is there a way to replace only certain parameter from one url request string?

Or why the "." keeps changing to "," comma?

**MY Code:**

```
Dim _value1 As Double = 62.234
Dim _value2 As String = "keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4"
Dim _value3 As Integer = "565"

Dim _URL as String = "https://myblog.com/?api&value1={_value1}&value2={_value2}&value3={_value3}"

Dim _urlFinal = url.Replace(",", ".")
```

**So the repalced urlFinal will look like like this:**

`https://myblog.com/?api&value1=62.234&value2=keyword1.keyword2.keyword3.keyword4&value3=565`

**But I need the url will look like this:**

`https://myblog.com/?api&value1=62.234&value2=keyword1,keyword2,keyword3,keyword4&value3=565`

Comment: Is that code being executed on a system where the culture is set to one that uses a comma as the decimal separator and a dot as a group separator instead of the other way around? One example of such a culture would be fr-FR, i.e. French. If that is the case and you can't change it then you should explicitly convert the number to text and specify the culture, using one that uses the separators you want, e.g. en-US, i.e. US English.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I will let this topic of because can't help my self, I found some "Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" topic I think i need to covert it before as string from decimal I will see thx for fast answer anyways appreciate